# LoadRunner should be with in AWS or OutSide of AWS?

Tags: testing, load, runner

I was trying to setup test environment for Performance testing using Load Runner, of a Multi tenant application hosted on AWS.

My question is, Can I run the LR tests from AWS and test an application which is also hosted on AWS. (Same data center but different servers?).

Or, should I run the LR tests from outside of the AWS environment with Application under test on AWS?

The goal is to perform Load testing and create the sizing document.

Answer (score 0):

Make the argument for each condition and evaluate which argument is strongest based upon representing the end user behavior and location.  You will run into a lot of technical "can" versus process or engineering "should" when you make these arguments, so qualify the "shoulds" against business risk, match to user behavior and testing best practices.